# What is the Java equivalent of a C# Graphics object? (more details included)

Tags: c#, java, forms, graphics

In a C# Windows form, there is a Graphics object which is used to draw images and shapes directly to the form. What is the equivalent in Java?

In case my question isn't clear enough, I wish to draw to a form in Java like I would in C#. I am aware of Applets and JApplets, but I want to do this in an actual form and not in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also [Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) in Java. (Surprise!)

Sometimes you need to cast the object to [Graphics2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) for more advanced graphics manipulations.

Comment: EhhhhhhhwhaaaAH? Wow. Thanks, that really _really_ helps. My projects can move forwards now!

Comment: @avatarmonkeykirby: +1 for your reaction :D

Answer (score 1):

The Graphics Class in Java:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html